# How to consume variable of a callback function within a service file and send it to app.component.ts file

Tags: amazon-s3, angular8

I'm using Amazon S3 bucket which has my files and I'm able to read the content of a particular file in my service file. But my approach is to take that content from the service file and consume it in my component file so that I can display the data of file in view. I'm facing a challenge that I have S3 method to get the object of file which is a callback function and it has content of file and I'm not able to access that content outside the function.

Service file:---

```
import { Injectable, Input, Output ,EventEmitter} from '@angular/core';
import * as AWS from 'aws-sdk';
import * as s3 from 'aws-sdk/clients/s3';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { NgxNavigationWithDataComponent } from 'ngx-navigation-with-data';
import { of } from 'rxjs';
import { FileUpload } from '../file-upload';
import { FilereadComponent } from '../fileread/fileread.component';
import { BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs'
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class UploadService {
  private fileContentSource = new BehaviorSubject('message');
  fileContent = this.fileContentSource.asObservable();
FOLDER = '';
  BUCKET = 'ewcompensation';
  userId: any;
  load_values_from_server = '';
  constructor(public navCtrl: NgxNavigationWithDataComponent) {
    this.userId = sessionStorage.getItem("userId");
  }
  changeFC(fileContent) {
    this.fileContentSource.next(fileContent)
  }
  public getS3Bucket(): any {
    const bucket = new s3(
      {
        accessKeyId: '',
        secretAccessKey: '',
        region: ''
      }
    );
    return bucket;
  }
  getEachFile(bucket, fileName) {

    const keyBucket = {
      Bucket: bucket,
      Key: fileName
    };

    this.getS3Bucket().getObject(keyBucket, function (err, data)  {
      if (err) {
        console.error(err);
      } else {
        const content = new TextDecoder('utf-8').decode(data.Body);
        console.log('myfilecontent : ' + content);
      }  
    });
    return of(keyBucket);
  }
uploadFile(file) {
    const params = {
      Bucket: this.BUCKET,
      Key: this.FOLDER + file.name,
      Body: file,
      // ACL: 'public-read'
    };
    this.getS3Bucket().upload(params, function (err, data) {
      if (err) {
        console.log('There was an error uploading your file: ', err);
        return false;
      }
      console.log('Successfully uploaded file.', data);
      return true;
    });
    return of(file);
  }
 getFiles(): Observable<Array<FileUpload>> {
    const fileUploads = new Array<FileUpload>();

    const params = {
      Bucket: this.BUCKET,
      Prefix: this.FOLDER
    };

    this.getS3Bucket().listObjects(params, function (err, data) {
      if (err) {
        console.log('There was an error getting your files: ' + err);
        return;
      }

      console.log('Successfully get files.', data);
      const fileDatas = data.Contents;
      fileDatas.forEach(function (file) {
        fileUploads.push(new FileUpload(file.Key, 'https://s3.amazonaws.com/' + params.Bucket + '/' + file.Key));
      });
    });
    return of(fileUploads);
  }
  ngOnInit() {
  }
}

app.component.ts file:-
constructor(public uploadService: UploadService, public navCtrl: NgxNavigationWithDataComponent , private router : RouterModule) {
    this.fileName = 'JSON file.txt';
    this.bucketName = 'ewcompensation';
    this.uploadService.getEachFile(this.bucketName,this.fileName).subscribe(response => {
     console.log(response)
     })
  }

this.getS3Bucket().getObject(keyBucket, function (err, data)  {//function to read the content of file
      if (err) {
        console.error(err);
      } else {
        const content = new TextDecoder('utf-8').decode(data.Body);
        console.log('myfilecontent : ' + content);// here it shows the content of my file.
      }
```

I want to send this content in my app.component.ts file, Kindly tell me some way how I can achieve this.